# XSLT to generate xsl fo from HTML with varying namespace

Tags: html, xslt, xml-namespaces, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have a XSLT file which is used for html to xsl-fo conversion using fop engine.
It has templates for HTML elements as shown below

```
<pre>

    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="html">
    //handle html element
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="head/title">
    //handle head/title elements
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>

</pre>
```

I need to convert all kinds of HTML files provided as input to the processor.
HTML files without namespace are processed without any issues.
However, some HTML files have name space (`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`)
in which case the fop processor is throwing exceptions.
What is the best way to handle this sort of cases? 
Can i create some template which ,based on the local-name(), call the correct template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preference in this kind of situation is to normalize the input before doing anything else, in a separate pass. This could be done with a template rule something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="lower-case(local-name())">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='html' or local-name()='HTML']">
  //handle html element
</xsl:template>
```

that will match `html` or `HTML` elements in any namespace.

Unfortunately HTML can have a LOT of variations, and also contains non-valid XML (e.g. tags that are not closed). If you want a real general solution you need a HTML parser.